# How to get id from many to many table which never present in one column

Tags: postgresql

I have table with many to many relation to `сategory` table. And my goal get category ids which never contains in `sub_category_id` column. Problem in case when some rows can contain ids in `main_category_id` and some row  can contain same id in `sub_category_id`. How to exclude ids which contains in `main_category_id` and in the same time present in `sub_category_id` in another rows?

I will try execute query like this but still faced with id which contains in `sub_category_id` (becsue in some rows this ids present in `main_category_id`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c0_.id


FROM category c0_ 

INNER JOIN category_relations c1_ ON c0_.id = c1_.main_category_id 
INNER JOIN category_relations c2_ ON c0_.id = c2_.sub_category_id 

WHERE (c0_.id = c1_.main_category_id AND c0_.id != c1_.sub_category_id)
```

structure my table

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for category_relations
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."category_relations";
CREATE TABLE "public"."category_relations" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "sub_category_id" int4,
  "main_category_id" int4,
  "created_at" timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp(0) NOT NULL
)
;

-- ----------------------------
-- Indexes structure for table category_relations
-- ----------------------------
CREATE INDEX "idx_d30c6d48c6c55574" ON "public"."category_relations" USING btree (
  "main_category_id" "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);
CREATE INDEX "idx_d30c6d48f7bfe87c" ON "public"."category_relations" USING btree (
  "sub_category_id" "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);

-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table category_relations
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."category_relations" ADD CONSTRAINT "category_relations_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

-- ----------------------------
-- Foreign Keys structure for table category_relations
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."category_relations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_d30c6d48c6c55574" FOREIGN KEY ("main_category_id") REFERENCES "public"."category" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
ALTER TABLE "public"."category_relations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_d30c6d48f7bfe87c" FOREIGN KEY ("sub_category_id") REFERENCES "public"."category" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: I tried to understand your explanation but this looks more like a Google translation. Would you be so kind and make it more verbose - and provide a few examples (one showing what you try to achieve and one showing what actually happens) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get only those category IDs which participate as a main category but at the same time do not participate as a sub category:

```
SELECT id FROM category
WHERE 
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM category_relations WHERE main_category_id = category.id)
  AND
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM category_relations WHERE sub_category_id = category.id)
```

Comment: awesome, like what I need